# can i inherit the standard class by using extends keyword in java

Tags: java

can i inherit the java standard class in my program using the "extends" keyword.just like:

```
class myclass extends standardJavaClass
{
     //code here
}
```

I am trying it but cannot find a solution. My main problem is:
Create a new class called AdvancedMath that inherits the standard math class of java.

Comment: Why do you want to extend the Math class? Its all `static` methods.

Comment: Read docs before asking question here..http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 3):

The `Math` class in Java is `final` and therefore you can't extend it.

Since all of it's method are `static`, I'd suggest to import it like:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

Comment: so is there any way to inherit the standard class?

Comment: Yes, by using the `extends` keyword **only** if the class is not `final`.

Comment: the java math class is final. Now how would i inherit it?

Comment: You can't inherit it because it is final!

Comment: you need not to do 3+2=6 ever..because 3+2=5 fine is good and done by java people..and thats why its final

Answer (score 0):

The class Java.lang.Math is Final class. It can't be extended.

Answer (score 0):

You can not extend `final` class and it is meaningless to extend a complete static `Math` class. Because you can not override all the stuff in it and you can only call them.

Also you can extend standard java class. For example, you can write your own handler based on `java.util.logging.Handler`